# Почему в запросе не выполняются все условия?

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Существует запрос:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish" AND post_content LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR post_title LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';
```

Мне нужно собрать из таблицы posts данные с условиями выше. Чтобы не возникло вопросов, опишу то, что хочу сделать. Поверить, является ли пост собственно постом, проверить, опубликован ли пост и есть ли соответствие по запросу в контенте поста либо в заголовке.

В итоге я получаю работающими два последних условия (проверку на соответствия в контенте и заголовке). Все остальные игнорируются.

Comment: @hamlet_is_dead, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Ну правильнее было бы так:

```
$sql = ' ...
  WHERE 1
    AND post_type = "post"
    AND post_status = "publish"
    AND (
        post_content LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
        OR post_title LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
    )
';
```